# How to created a scrollable column with a container and listview builder as child in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to make a view where there will be a container with some data and below that a list of some other data. And I want both of them to scroll together. So for that I use a singlechildscrollview (physics: ScrollPhysics(),) inside that I used a column and inside column I used the container and a listview builder(shrinkWrap: true,physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),). But when did so I got an exception error.

**
FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
**

Then I tried the same code after wraping builder with Expended(). I got this error.
**
FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
**

** MY Code **

```
import 'package:Healthwise/helpers/dataVariables.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import '../helpers/backEnd.dart';
import '../helpers/frontEnd.dart';

class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ResultPage> createState() => _ResultPageState();
}

class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {
  // String docId = '';
  String objectToString = '';

  // List of string for storing..
  var dataAsString = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // getUsers();
    getUserById();
  }

  getUserById() {
    String id = itemName.toLowerCase().trim();

    fruitInfoDoc.doc(id).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      // final x = doc.data();
      // docId= doc.id;
      objectToString = doc.data().toString();
      String temp = '';
      // print(doc.data());
      // print(doc.id);
      int i = 1;

      bool end = false;
      //We are just parsing the object into string.
      while (objectToString[i] != '}') {
        if (objectToString[i - 1] == ' ' && objectToString[i - 2] == ':') {
          while (objectToString[i] != ',' && end != true) {
            temp += objectToString[i];
            if (objectToString[i + 1] != '}') {
              i++;
            } else {
              end = true;
            }
          }
          //Here I add all the strings to list...
          // This line works fine.
          dataAsString.add(temp);
          temp = '';
          print("The code below this line prints everything perfectly");
          print(dataAsString.length);
          print(dataAsString);
        }
        i++;
      }

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: primary_color,
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                itemName.trim().toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    //Fruit Name
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    fontSize: 15),
              ),
            )),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 50, 50),
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      if (dataAsString.length > 0) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: dataAsString.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return EditedListTile(
                                dataAsString: dataAsString,
                                index: index,
                              );
                            });
                      } else {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't use your code to debug, here is something similar to what you're trying to do. You were getting that error because you didn't have your Expanded widgets in correct place.

You have you're entire page scrollable with container inside that has scrollable Listview or remove Listview and add other widget at is place.

Below that you have another widget scrollable Listview, you can replace that with other widget and but keep Expanded widget as it is.

[For more info on Expanded Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

```
class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ResultPage> createState() => _ResultPageState();
}

class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {
  // String docId = '';
  String objectToString = '';

  // List of string for storing..
  List<String> list = List<String>.generate(100, (counter) => "Item $counter");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'itemName'.trim().toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  //Fruit Name
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  fontSize: 15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 50, 50),
                    width: 100,
                    child: ListView.builder(
//                   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Uncomment this to stop scroll
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text(list[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
//                   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Uncomment this to stop scroll
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(list[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```